# writing a typesafe visitor with labeled rules

Tags: label, antlr, antlr4, visitor-pattern

I am migrating my prototype from a listener to a visitor pattern. In the prototype, I have a grammar fragment like this:

```
thingList: thing+ ;

thing
  : A aSpec    # aRule
  | B bSpec    # bRule
  ;
```

Moving to a visitor pattern, I am not sure how I write `visitThingList`. Every visitor returns a specializes subclass of "Node", and I would love somehow when to be able to write something like this, say a "thingList" cares about the first thing in the list some how ...

```
visitThingList(cx: ThingListContext): ast.ThingList {
  ...
  const firstThing = super.visit(cx.thing(0));
```

The problem with this is in typing. Each visit returns a specialized type which is a subclass of `ast.Node`. Because I am using `super.visit`, the return value will be the base class
of my node tree. However, I know because I am looking at the grammar
and because I wrote both `vistARule` and `visitBRule` that the result of the visit will be of type `ast.Thing`.

So we make visitThingList express it's expectation with cast ...

```
visitThingList(cx: ThingListContext): ast.ThingList {
  const firstThing = super.visit(cx.thing(0));
  if (!firstThing instanceof ast.Thing) {
    throw "no matching visitor for thing";
  }
  // firstThing is now known to be of type ast.Thing
  ...
```

In much of my translator, type problems with ast Nodes are a compile time issue, I fix them in my editor. In this case, I am producing a more fragile walk, which will only reveal the fragility at runtime and then only with certain inputs.

I think I could change my grammar, to make it possible to encode the
type expectations of `vistThingList()` by creating a `vistThing()` entry point

```
thingList: thing+ ;
thing: aRule | bRule;
aRule: A aSpec;
bRule: B bSpec;
```

With `vistThing()` typed to match the expectation:

```
visitThing(cx: ThingContext): ast.Thing { }
visitThingList(cx: ThingListContext) {
  const firstThing: ast.Thing = this.visitThing(cx.thing(0));
```

Now `visitThingList` can call `this.visitThing()` and the type enforcement of making sure all rules that a `thing` matches return `ast.Thing` belongs to `visitThing()`. If I do create a new rule for thing, the compiler will force me to change the return type of `visitThing()` and if I make it return something which is NOT a thing, `visitThingList()` will show type errors.

This also seems wrong though, because I don't feel like I should have to change my grammar in order to visit it.

I am new to ANTLR and wondering if there is a better pattern or approach to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I was using the listener pattern, I wrote something like:
>
> ```
> enterThing(cx: ThingContext) { }
> enterARule(cx : ARuleContext) { }
> enterBRule(cx : BRuleContext) { }
> ```

Not quite: for a labeled rule like `thing`, the listener will not contain `enterThing(...)` and `exitThing(...)` methods. Only the `enter...` and `exit...` methods for the labels `aSpec` and `bSpec` will be created.

> How would I write the visitor walk without changing the grammar?

I don't understand why you need to change the grammar. When you keep the grammar like you mentioned:

```
thingList: thing+ ;

thing
  : A aSpec    # aRule
  | B bSpec    # bRule
  ;
```

then the following visitor could be used (again, there is no `visitThing(...)` method!):

```java
public class TestVisitor extends TBaseVisitor<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object visitThingList(TParser.ThingListContext ctx) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public Object visitARule(TParser.ARuleContext ctx) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public Object visitBRule(TParser.BRuleContext ctx) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public Object visitASpec(TParser.ASpecContext ctx) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public Object visitBSpec(TParser.BSpecContext ctx) {
        ...
    }
}
```

### EDIT

> I do not know how, as i iterate over that, to call the correct visitor for each element

You don't need to know. You can simply call the visitor's (super) `visit(...)` method and the correct method will be invoked:

```java
class TestVisitor extends TBaseVisitor<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object visitThingList(TParser.ThingListContext ctx) {
        for (TParser.ThingContext child : ctx.thing()) {
            super.visit(child);
        }
        return null;
    }

    ...
}
```

And you don't even need to implement all methods. The ones you don't implement, will have a default `visitChildren(ctx)` in them, causing (as the name suggests) all child nodes under them being traversed.

In your case, the following visitor will already cause the `visitASpec` and `visitBSpec` being invoked:

```java
class TestVisitor extends TBaseVisitor<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object visitASpec(TParser.ASpecContext ctx) {
        System.out.println("visitASpec");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object visitBSpec(TParser.BSpecContext ctx) {
        System.out.println("visitBSpec");
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can test this (in Java) like this:

```java
String source = "... your input here ...";
TLexer lexer = new TLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
TestVisitor visitor = new TestVisitor();
visitor.visit(parser.thingList());
```

Comment: Thanks, these things I knew. What I do not know is how `visitThingList` visits the rules it contains because up until now, when I wrote a visitor, I was always grabbing each sub rule, and calling the sub rule visitor myself explicit to get the result to compose the value of the parent rule. ( As in the example I gave with the changed grammar) Because `ctx.thing()` is an array of `ThingContext` objects, I do not know how, as i iterate over that, to call the correct visitor for each element.

Comment: "Thanks, these things I knew" by including things in your question that were incorrect, I got the impression you didn't know it. Checkout my edited answer @MichaelToy

Comment: Hey @BartKiers -- Your answer was fantastic, it helped me refine my unease to a better question. I feel like I got fully "answered", and am now at the real question I was asking. I want you to get all credit for wading through my confusion and getting me the information I needed to ask a better question. Trying to figure out how to leave a good artifact on stackoverflow when the original question was "-1"d for being a bad question, I edited the question. Just want to shout out, your answers were very helpful.

Comment: ... and at this point, I have a working translator, so I am no longer entirely "new to ANTLR", but I still have this little warty problem in a few places in my translator, so it is still a real question for me.